# mysql: secure_file_priv (again)

Tags: mysql

Running MySql 5.5.53 on Ubuntu 14.04.5. When importing data from a text file (load data infil $FIL INTO TABLE &c) I get the dreaded complaint that it cannot be done because of secure_file_priv

When consulted, the value of secure_file_priv is /var/lib/mysql-files , which I cannot change from inside mysql, neither do I find it in any config file so I reckon it must be hard-coded.

Tried to change the value by creating a file /etc/mysql/conf.d/secure_file_priv, with contents

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv=""
```

then restarted mysql with

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
# wait for mysqld process to terminate
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

and found no change. The import still gives the same error and mysql still reports the *secure_file_priv* variable at its default value.

Then changed my little file to read

```
[mysql]
secure_file_priv=""
```

and restarted mysql again, with the exact same (lack of) result.

What is the *exact* way to set this variable for my particular mysql installation? Or what else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check whether mysql-files directory is there in /var/lib.
Because it is not generated on its own while upgraded from mysql-5.5.52 to 5.5.53.
Lots of people had faced this issue.
It's a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/1637280

So if is not generated then please create this directory manually using follwing commands and then restart mysql server.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files  
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-files/  
sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql-files/
```

Comment: Dear, the directory does exist and it always has. Actually, as you could see above, I did create the correct files in it, only the file extension was incorrect. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: extra configuration files must have a name ending in ".cnf"
It says so at the end of my.cnf, as usual careful reading was sufficient.